# Copy file to another folder upon creation using FileSystemWatcher - C#

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

New to C# - I need to build a console app to monitor a set of folders on a Windows 2019 Server and copy any newly-created .txt files to another folder, using the same file name.  I need assistance with the `Copy` method. This is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Folderwatch
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\me\Documents\SomeFolder";

            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(sourcePath);

            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            watcher.Filter = "*.log";


            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);


            // Wait for the user to quit the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Monitoring File System Activity on {0}.", sourcePath);
            Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit.");
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;

        }

        // Define the event handlers. 

        private static void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Specify what is done when a file is created.
            string destPath = @"C:\Users\pdeeb\Desktop\Temp";
            string sourceFile = ??
            string destFile = Path.Combine(destPath, sourceFile);
            File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
        }

    }
}
```

I feel I may be overcomplicating a simple task - I just want to copy that created file to the `destPath` with the same file name, and allow overwrites.  How should I be defining the `sourceFile` variable, or am I even on the right track with this approach?

Comment: Check out the `FileSystemEventArgs e` argument. It has some interesting [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemeventargs.fullpath). :-)

Comment: I think the edge cases are interesting.  To me the interesting part of this question will be how to deal with what happens when the file is created, but still empty, because it hasn't finished being written to yet (or is partially  complete).  Or you try to copy it and it's still locked by the creator.  (You do mean *copy*, not *move*, right?) Or if the destination file cannot be overwritten because it is locked. Or if the writer writes the file in several passes by appending, and you removed the original (probably a bad idea).

Comment: @Wyck all good points.  Yes definitely copy vs. move.  Once I get my arms around the basics, I will then definitely look into handling files that are not instantaneous in their creation (I think I may have seen a couple posts here on the subject).  There would never be a case of the original being removed.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias in the `OnCreated` method, I'm using `string createdFile = e.Name` to get the created file name, but it's giving me the entire folder path instead of just the file name.  Any suggestions?  Here is the reference I'm using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemeventargs?view=netcore-3.1#properties

Comment: You could use the [`Path.GetFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename) method. ==> *"Returns the file name and extension of the specified path string."*